# UDP to Serial port

Tags: port, udp, serial, netcat, socat

I look for some solution for connect serial/UART port by UDP connection to another PC.
Now I use socat and have connection , but with lost packages, and slow transfer.
Can I use netcat for this, maybe it will get better solution?
Can I get some example for this?
Thank a lot.

Comment: You will always risk losing packets with UDP. It's the nature of the protocol.

Comment: You can use a serial interface as the layer-1 for a network stack. You need to pick a layer-2 protocol that can use a serial interface. There are various protocols (PPP, HDCL, SLIP, etc.) that you could use.

Comment: Why exactly do you need UDP? What OSes do you run?

Comment: @NStorm i think and belive due the thinking of "speed-feature"